# Add unit to python format function

Tags: python

Is it possible to add a unit ($) to the following format function?

```
def comma(x, pos):
        return format(x, "6,.0f")
```

I've tried

```
return "$" + format(x, "6,.0f")
```

but there is too much space between the number and dollar sign on the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format to a minimum of six characters *after* adding the currency symbol:

```
>>> format("${:,.0f}".format(99.9), ">6s")
'  $100'
>>> format("${:,.0f}".format(99), ">6s")
'   $99'
>>> format("${:,.0f}".format(9999), ">6s")
'$9,999'
```

Note that this means that the limit includes the `$` and `,`.